# Extract values based on a pattern in a list python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract values based on certain pattern in a list.

```
**Example:**
ticker=['HF (NYSE) (81%);BPO (NEW YORK)]']

**Expected Output:**
Tickercode-HF;BPO
StockCode-NYSE;NEW YORK
Relevancescore-81;0

**My code**:
Tickercode=[x for x in ticker if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+[\w\.-]+', x)]
Stockcode=[x for x in ticker if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+(%)+[\w\.-]+', x)]
Relevancescore=[x for x in ticker if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+(%)+[\w\.-]+', x)]

**My output:**
['HF (NYSE) (81%);BPO (NEW YORK)]']
[]
[]
```

But i am getting wrong output. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: I see no error in your output.

Comment: Not getting error. But i am getting wrong output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firs, each item of `ticker` contains multiple records separated by semicolon, so I recommend normalize ticker. Then iterate over strings and extract info using 
pattern `'(\w+) \(([\w ]+)\)( \(([\d]+)%\))?'`.

```
import re

ticker=['HF (NYSE) (81%);BPO (NEW YORK)]']
ticker=[y for x in ticker for y in x.split(';')]

Tickercode=[]
Stockcode=[]
Relevancescore=[]

for s in ticker:
    m = re.search(r'(\w+) \(([\w ]+)\)( \(([\d]+)%\))?', s)
    Tickercode.append(m.group(1))
    Stockcode.append(m.group(2))
    Relevancescore.append(m.group(4))

print(Tickercode)
print(Stockcode)
print(Relevancescore)
```

Output:

```
['HF', 'BPO']
['NYSE', 'NEW YORK']
['81', None]
```

**Update**:

Using `re.search` instead of `re.match` which will match pattern from start of string. Your input have a leading white space, causing it failed.

You can add this to print which string doesn't match.

```
    if m is None:
        print('%s cannot be matched' % s)
        continue
```

Comment: It throws me error for this input:['BAC (NYSE) (92%); BAC (LSE) (92%); 8648 (TSE) (92%); VNTV (NYSE) (92%); JPM (NYSE) (90%); JPM (LSE) (90%)]'] Error i am getting is:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Its failing again for same input. I am wondering why its failing again

Comment: Yeah it works. I tried to change a little bit.m = re.search(r'(\w+) (\w+)(\(([\d]+)%\))?', s). How about this case? ['INTEL CORP (82%)', ' AUTODESK INC (54%)', ' ACCENTURE PLC (54%)', ' PEPSICO INC (53%)', ' VASCULAR SOLUTIONS INC (51%)'] I am not able to extract % value

Comment: `(` and `)` need to be escaped.

Comment: How will i do that. I am getting None output only.m = re.search(r'(\w+)\ (\w+)(\(([\d]+)%)\)?', s)

Comment: Can you please help on this issue

Comment: To match the literals '(' or ')', use '\(' or '\)'. This is called escape.

Comment: yeah can you tell me how to do it in my code. I am trying to escape the braces but still it is not getting correct result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're building up each of your lists from the input.  You're telling it, "make a list of the input if the input matches my regular expression".   The `re.match()` only matches against the beginning of a string, so the only regex that matches is the one that matches against the ticker symbol itself.

I've reorganized your code a bit below to show how it can work.

- Use re.compile() to the regex doesn't have to be created each time
- Use re.search() so you can find your embedded patterns
- Use match.group(1) to get the matching part of the query, not the whole of the input.
- Break up your input so you're only handling one group at a time

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import re

  # Example:
  ticker=['HF (NYSE) (81%);BPO (NEW YORK)]']

  # **Expected Output:**
  # Tickercode-HF;BPO
  # StockCode-NYSE;NEW YORK
  # Relevancescore-81;0

  tickercode=[]
  stockcode=[]
  relevancescore=[]

  ticker_re = re.compile(r'^\s*([A-Z]+)')
  stock_re = re.compile(r'\(([\w ]+)\)')
  relevance_re = re.compile(r'\((\d+)%\)')

  for tick in ticker:
      for stockinfo in tick.split(";"):
          ticker_match = ticker_re.search(stockinfo)
          stock_match = stock_re.search(stockinfo)
          relevance_match = relevance_re.search(stockinfo)

          ticker_code = ticker_match.group(1) if ticker_match else ''
          stock_code = stock_match.group(1) if stock_match else ''
          relevance_score = relevance_match.group(1) if relevance_match else '0'

          tickercode.append(ticker_code)
          stockcode.append(stock_code)
          relevancescore.append(relevance_score)

  print 'Tickercode-' + ';'.join(tickercode)
  print 'StockCode-' + ';'.join(stockcode)
  print 'Relevancescore-' + ';'.join(relevancescore)
  ```

Comment: ['BAC (NYSE) (92%); BAC (LSE) (92%); 8648 (TSE) (92%); VNTV (NYSE) (92%); JPM (NYSE) (90%); JPM (LSE) (90%)]']
 when i run for the above ticker list, i am getting wrong output.Output is:BAC,;;;

Comment: @Mho - Because now your input has spaces after the semi-colons.  Fixed the ticker regex accordingly.